# How to avoid retaining string values in C in function calls

Tags: c

Edit: solution was to use strdup()

I have re-asked my question. 
[How to create to a new string to use as a key everytime I call a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083576/how-to-create-to-a-new-string-to-use-as-a-key-everytime-i-call-a-function)

I want to a fresh variable char[] newer everytime my function is called. The reason is because I set my key as newer in a global hashmap. I don't want keys being modified everytime I call the function and modify newer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void new(){
    char  newer[45];
    printf("%s\n", newer);
    strncat(newer,"hi",1235);
}
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        new();
    }
}
```

My current output is

```
hi                                                                                                                                            
hihi                                                                                                                                          
hihihi                                                                                                                                        
hihihihi                                                                                                                                      
hihihihihi
```

but I want it to be

```
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
```

Edit: I forgot to mention the purpose of my code.
I'm not able to post the code completely since it's a school project. Basically let's say I have a global hashmap that takes (key,value) pairs. Everytime I call the `new()` it should add a new entry to the hashmap. For example I have a function `add` which is supposed to `add (key = newer, value = "something")` to the global hashmap. I want `hashmap = { key1="hi":value1="stuff",key2="hihi":value2=stuff2"}` after 2 calls to the function. 
For some reason my hashmap ends up being `{key1="hi:value1="stuff"}` after 1 call and then `{key1="hihi":value1="stuff",key2="hihi":value2="stuff2"}` after 2 calls. The reason is because the `key1 = newer` and `key2 = newer` so thus `key1=key2`. This means that everytime I modify variable `newer` in a function call, it literally changes my previous key's values

For example in python I could do the following since everytime I call newer, it is a fresh variable that has no relationship with previous calls using newer.

```
def new(i,diction):
    newer = "hi" * i
    diction[newer] = "stuff" + str(i)


diction = {}
for i in range(10):
    new(i,diction)

print(diction)
```

Essentially result is 
`{'': 'stuff0', 'hihi': 'stuff2', 'hihihihihihi': 'stuff6', 'hi': 'stuff1', 'hihihi': 'stuff3', 'hihihihi': 'stuff4', 'hihihihihihihi': 'stuff7
', 'hihihihihihihihihi': 'stuff9', 'hihihihihihihihi': 'stuff8', 'hihihihihi': 'stuff5'}`

I want to ask how to do the same thing in C

Comment: you cannot `strncat` to an uninitalized array either.

Comment: And your array is uninitialized the first time you call the function... and just luckily contains some garbage from previous runs

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It's uninitialized **every** time they call the function.

Comment: @Blastfurnace oops I blame `ENOCOFFE`

Comment: What the hell are you thinking here > `strncat(newer,"hi",1235);`. `newer` is a `char[45]`, so why are you passing in `1235` as the size limit for `strncat`? The max you can concat here is `44 - len(newer)`, which, because `newer` isn't initialised properly is UB

Comment: Please check [strncat](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncat) last argument. You can't give last argument as some random number like `1235`, it should be dest buffer size.

Comment: yeah that's true about sizes but anyways, could someone help me with hashmap keys being mutable and changing everytime I call function since my hashmap key is the variable newer.

Comment: It sounds like your hashmap keys are all pointers to the same `char` array. You need to rethink what you're doing. Either make the keys `char[45]` or dynamically allocate memory for each key string.

Comment: Looks like what you want to ask, and what you are actually asking, are quit different. I suggest you accept one of the answers which answer *this* question, and ask a new question with better code and explanation. Try to create [MCVE] which show the *real* problem.

Comment: @Blastfurnace. I'm not familiar with C. If I were to do this same function in python, this is how I would do it.

Comment: If you don't know C this will be difficult. I suggest you take some time to learn more about object lifetimes and memory management. This question doesn't really illustrate the problem you're asking about. Note that C is a much lower-level language and you must do **everything** that python is hiding or making simple.

Comment: @Blastfurnace could you give an example of "Either make the keys char[45] or dynamically allocate memory for each key string"

Comment: I don't know that your data structure looks so this is a guess. Instead of a `char*` key field make it a `char[45]` so the key is stored inside the table entry. Or you could `malloc` memory for the `char*` field and copy the string into it. That would mean correctly using `free` to avoid a memory leak (manual memory management is a pain in the butt, I prefer C++ because of this).

Comment: I have re-written my question as requested. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083576/how-to-create-to-a-new-string-to-use-as-a-key-everytime-i-call-a-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to reset the value of the char[] newer everytime my new function is called.

All you need is to initialise it properly:

```
char newer[45] = "";
```

As a general rule, you should always initialise local variable before using it. Failing to do so will usually lead to unexpected behaviour as you've seen in your code.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to reset newer[45]. Even though it's not in my code sample, I use the value of newer[45] as a key to a hashmap struct. If I do what you suggested then my key in hashmap struct would change from "hi" to "" temporarily which poses a problem.

Comment: That seems completely contradict to what you said in the question: "I want to reset the value of the char[] newer everytime"

Comment: @AmbitiousIntern In the code you posted the array's lifetime begins when the function is called so initializing it before calling `strncat` is correct.  You should post code that actually reproduces your problem because what you're showing now is a simple and avoidable bug.

Comment: I'm not able to post the code completely since it's a school project. Basically let's say I have a global hashmap that takes (key,value) pairs. Everytime I call the new() it should add a new entry to the hashmap. For example I have a function "add" which is supposed to add (key = newer, value = "something") to the global hashmap. I want hashmap = { key1="hi":value1="stuff",key2="hihi":value2=stuff2"} after 2 calls to the function.

Comment: For some reason my hashmap ends up being {key1="hi:value1="stuff"} after 1 call and then{key1="hihi":value1="stuff",key2="hihi":value2="stuff2"} after 2 calls. The reason is because the key1 = newer and key2 = newer so thus key1=key2.  This means that everytime I modify variable newer in a function call, it literally changes my previous key's values

Comment: @AmbitiousIntern This is not what Blastfurnace said. You should provide a complete example that shows your problem, not the code you're working on.

Comment: As a general rule, it is a bad code smell if *every* variable is explicitly initialized. This just proves that you don't know what you are doing. You need to *assign a value* to a variable before you *read* it.

Comment: @thebusybee well that's what a general rule is, better to initialise an variable than leaving it in an unspecified state. You can say for some scenarios it may not be necessary, but that's not a general rule.

Comment: No, it's not about "some scenarios", it's about firm knowledge of the tool (i.e. the programming language) we use. I'd rather like people *knowing consciously* than *following rules blindly*. You wouldn't give a general rule like "Cook all water before you drink it" just because this is right for most areas in the world, will you?

Comment: @thebusybee ok, maybe refer to this? That should be more reliable than other people just making up their own rule: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es20-always-initialize-an-object

Comment: I have rewritten my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083576/how-to-create-to-a-new-string-to-use-as-a-key-everytime-i-call-a-function

Comment: Even if you refer to a C++ style guide when the OP's language is C, the rule you link to supports my point: Don't initialize a variable *blindly*. But since C++ is a worse language than C, to be honest one of the worst I learned the last 30+ years in my career as developer in safety-critical areas, it needs such stronger-than-technically-necessary rules.

Comment: @AmbitiousIntern Is the string stored in the hashmap, or only a pointer to the string? Since the variable `newer` is destroyed when `new` returns, you aren't allowed to use any pointers to it after that, and doing so can have unpredictable results.

Answer (score 1):

Made a small modification to your program as below.And now it's showing expected output:
1)initilized the char array.
2)appended hi to array and size modified to 2
3)print it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void new()
{
    char  newer[45]="";
    strncat(newer,"hi",2);
    printf("%s\n", newer);
}
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        new();
    }
}
```