# How to create to a new string to use as a key everytime I call a function?

Tags: c

I am not able to post my project code in C due to school rules.

Here is a previous question I asked but was recommended to create a new question.
[How to avoid retaining string values in C in function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59082088/how-to-avoid-retaining-string-values-in-c-in-function-calls)

In python I can do the following since everytime I call newer, it is a fresh variable that has no relationship with newer in previous calls.

```
def new(i,diction):
    newer = "hi" * i
    diction[newer] = "stuff" + str(i)


diction = {}
for i in range(3):
    new(i,diction)

print(diction)
```

Essentially the desired result is
{'': 'stuff0', 'hi': 'stuff1', 'hihi': 'stuff2'}

However in C, I can't user newer as a key since if I modify newer in a new function call, then all my keys created from previous calls would change.

I want to ask how to do the same thing in C that I did in python.

When I mention modifying newer in C, this is what I mean.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void new(){
    char  newer[4000000];
    printf("%s\n", newer);
    strncat(newer,"hi",1235);
    //use newer as a key to a hashmap.

}
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        new();
    }
}
```

Everytime I change newer, all the keys in my hashmap change. So here is how my hashmap in C looks like after each function call

First call result:
{'': 'stuff0'}

Second call result:
{'hihi': 'stuff0','hihi': 'stuff1'}

Third call result:
{'hihi': 'stuff0', 'hihi': 'stuff1', 'hihi': 'stuff2'}

Comment: Ok so if I don't use char pointers as the key, what should I use?

Comment: What hash map ? The code you show doesn't do that. Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that exhibits the problem you have. Make sure to include the input you gave and the output you expected instead. Otherwise, all we can do is guess.

Comment: You don't need to post the hashmap code - just create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that has the same behavior and post that.

Comment: I used char *newer = strdup("hi",2); to initialize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you only store the *pointer* to the key in the map.

You need to store a *copy* of the key instead, but only use it in case of hash-collisions. One way to store a copy of the key is to use the non-standard but commonly available `strdup` function.

---

Using pointer to the key in the map brings other problems besides the one you see. Especially considering that in the code you show you use a *local* array for the key, which means the pointer will become invalid once the function `new` returns and `newer` ends its life.

Also in the code you show you print the contents of `newer` before it's initialized, and its contents is *indeterminate*.

This uninitialized contents of `newer` is also problematic for the `strncat` call, as it will search for the terminator to know where to append the string. And that could theoretically lead to the function going out of bounds of the array in that search. If you just want to copy a string into `newer` use `strcpy` instead.

You also use close to 4 MiB for the array, and considering that the compiler will put it on a very limited stack you waste a lot of space (not to mention that your program won't run on Windows where the default stack is only a single MiB).

Comment: Ok I understand that I shouldn't use a char pointer. Could you provide a code example of storing a hash? Also could you provide an example of how to store a copy of the key?

Comment: I'm using strdup in my newer but get the following error.... bank: malloc.c:2401: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.

Comment: Am I supposed to call strdup in my new or main function? Also where would I free it?

Comment: @AmbitiousIntern That looks like a run-time assertion, which means your program crashed as it did something bad. Use a debugger to find out where in your code the crash happened, and if you can't figure it out yourself then please post a new question about that problem. But before that please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and learn how to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: programmar dude. Strdup() was successful!!